# ng-model wont update when <select> is changed with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to make a custom dropdown box using javascript and anglersJS to bind the data to the select.
Not all the code is here, but the way that it should work is that the user clicks a div(which acts as the option select), that is created with code that isn't posted, then the div calls a function to change the select tags selected index and value,(does not directly change the model in the $scope). The data-ng-model should be updating, however, the model does not update its value.

I have tried calling $apply() and $digest() and neither work.
The select tag is showing that the index and value have change but model is not picking it up.

Note: data-bp-placeholder is used by my Javascript to create the custom dropdown list.

HTML

```
<div class="bp-select" data-bp-placeholder="Choose">
    <select data-ng-model="count.amount">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
selectElement.selectedIndex = i;
selectElement.value = optionList[i].value;
```

'selectElement' is the select tag, 'i' is the index, and 'optionsList' is just the list of the options tags' values.

How can i get ng-model to update its value after the select tag's value is changed.

Comment: The `ng-model` direcitve only updates the scope model when the user selects a value. It does not update the scope model when JavaScript modifies the `value` property of the `<select>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be manipulating the DOM directly which you should avoid as AngularJs may not recognize it.
To do the correct AngularJs way, you need to change two places:

- Assign the user input to the model not to the DOM element, as already answered
- Your `data-bp-placeholder` handler seems to dynamically add option values to the `selectElement` by direct DOM manipulation (by using `appendChild` I suppose). You should maybe try this instead:

```
$scope.count.amounts = Array.from(Array(10).keys()); // Create scope array variable of whatever your list is
```

Then your HTML may look like this, possibly without needing `data-bp-placeholder`:

```
<select data-ng-model="count.amount" data-ng-options="amount for amount in count.amounts">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-model` direcitve only updates the scope model when the user selects a value. It does not update the scope model when JavaScript modifies the `value` property of the `<select>` element.

```html
<select data-ng-model="count.amount">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

To update the scope model from JavaScript:

```
$scope.count.amount = "5";
```

Be sure to use strings and not numbers.